# How can I use \psgraph with polar axes?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

### With `pspicture`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=100}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](3,360)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{sin(3*x)+2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `psgraph`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=100}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[linecolor=gray](3,360){4cm}{4cm}
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{sin(3*x)+2}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I use `psgraph` with polar axes?

Comment: How come you want to use `psgraph`? Is it so that you can specify the width and height? I'm interested because I have another solution (if that's the case)...

Comment: Because I want to make every graph use `psgraph` for the sake of consistency. I reserve `pspicture` is for drawing non-graph.

Comment: what advantages does `psgraph` offer over `pspicture`?

Comment: @cmhughes: With `psgraph`, we can specify the size of graph in advance and the vertical and horizontal units are automatically adjusted. It is useful for the case in which we have a dimension constraint in our articles, books, or any documents. For example, if I want to put the graph in the `marginpar`, it is much better if we specify the dimension of the graph (via `psgraph`) to be equal to the width of the `marginpar` such that we don't need to scale the graph with `width=\linewidth` (of `includegraphics`) which badly also affects the size of labels attached to the graph.

Comment: I have a solution that can fix this for `psgraph` - I'll post it as an answer at some point (too busy at the moment)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense to use `\psgraph` here: it is a simple scaling of the graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\frame{\psscaleboxto(4cm,4cm){%
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=100,plotstyle=curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](3,360)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{sin(3*x)+2}
\end{pspicture}}}
\frame{\psscaleboxto(4cm,4cm){%
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=100,plotstyle=curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.2,-0.5)(4,4)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](3,90)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{0}{Pi2}{sin(3*x)+2}
\end{pspicture}}}

\rule{4cm}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=10000,plotstyle=curve}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](3,360)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=blue!60,
      opacity=0.5,linecolor=red]{0}{20 Pi mul}{sin(3*x)+2*cos(x/2)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second `axesstyle=polar` can be removed to save more keystrokes.

Comment: I love keystrokes ...

Comment: The axis is in degrees, but the function domain is specified in radians. Is it possible to specify the function domain in degrees?

Comment: sure, it is ... it is the default

Comment: @Herbert: If I use `\psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{0}{360}{sin(3*x)+2}`, I don't get the same plot.

Comment: sure, the function is in algebraic mode, which is always in radian: `{3 x mul sin 2 add}` and, of course, without the algebraic option.

Comment: @Herbert: ... and PGF is always in degrees.

Comment: no: with `algebraic` PSTricks _switches_ to radian ... :-)

Comment: @Herbert: If I understand correctly, you have to choose between algebraic + radians, or RPN + degrees, right? You can't have algebraic + degrees, or RPN + radians? `=)`

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun with PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[enlargelimits=false, xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$]
\addplot [thick, red, domain=0:360, samples=100] {sin(3*x)+2};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to specify the function and domain in terms of radians, set `data cs=polarrad`. this can be useful if you want to plot a data file that uses radians, for instance.

If you want to plot a function with `data cs=polarrad`, note that the math parser will still expect the input to trigonometric functions to be in degrees, so you'll have to use `sin(deg(...))` instead of `sin(...)`, for example.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, tikz has no `tikzgraph` which is the equivalent of `psgraph`.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch: Doesn't `psgraph` just scale the coordinates as needed? PGFPlots does this.

Comment: @Jake: the step width is counted in degrees. Are radians also possible?

Comment: Can you make the angle in degrees with `\circ`? Without `\circ` ones might think the angle in radian.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch: Sure. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jake: with `data cs=polarrad` I'll get `Dimension too large` ...

Comment: @Jake: Ah yes, that makes sense. However, I do not get the image with `domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, data cs=polarrad`

Comment: I see, one has also to change the equation: `x*180/pi`. Not really nice ...

Comment: Where is the sense of `data cs=polarrad` if you still have to use degrees??

Comment: We are plotting a function, not a data file

Comment: it's ok, I wanted only to know how it is done with `pgfplots`

Comment: I am not complaining ...

Comment: No, I want to understand things, that's all ...

Answer (score 2):

> *With psgraph, we can specify the size of graph in advance and the
>   vertical and horizontal units are automatically adjusted.*

The same thing troubled me when I first started using [`pstricks`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pstricks)  - we can specify `xunit` and `yunit` using `psset`, but we simply have to live with whatever the width and height of the figure turn out to be. As far as I could tell, there was no way to specify the *width* and/or *height* and then calculate `xunit` and `yunit`.

Of course, a little bit of mathematics can be invoked and, given a `width` and values of `xmin` and `xmax`, we can calculate `xunit`; similarly for a `height`, with given values of `ymin` and `ymax` we can compute `yunit`.

The code below defines a `setwindow` command that is invoked in the following way:

```
\setwindow[optional height ratio]{xmin}{xmax}{ymin}{ymax}{\figurewidth}
```

For example, it can be used as

```
\setlength{\figurewidth}{.5\textwidth}
\setwindow{0}{-.5}{3}{3}{\figurewidth}
```

which will set the `pspicture` environment to have width and height of half of the text width, with `xmin=0`, `ymin=-.5`, `xmax=3`, and `ymax=3`.

The optional argument can be used to scale the height with respect to the width. For example, using

```
\setwindow[.5]{0}{-.5}{3}{3}{\figurewidth}
```

will set the height of the `pspicture` to be half of the width. Using

```
\setwindow[.25]{0}{-.5}{3}{3}{\figurewidth}
```

will set the height to be a quarter of the width.

Here's a complete example to play with - I hope it's useful!

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\newlength{\figurewidth}
% setwindow command: takes 6 arguments (1st is optional)
%       [1]. aspect ratio (height = aspect ratio * width) default=1
%         2. xmin (number)
%         3. ymin (number)
%         4. xmax (number)
%         5. ymax (number)
%         6. figurewidth (length)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setwindow}[6][1]{\def\xmin{#2}%
    \def\ymin{#3}%
    \def\xmax{#4}%
    \def\ymax{#5}%
    % set up xunit
    \pstFPsub\viewingwidth{#4}{#2}%
    \pstFPdiv\result{\strip@pt#6}{\viewingwidth}%
    \psset{xunit=\result pt}
    % set up yunit
    \pstFPsub\viewingheight{#5}{#3}%
    \pstFPdiv\result{\strip@pt#6}{\viewingheight}%
    % set up aspect ratio
    \pstFPmul\result{\result}{#1}%
    \psset{yunit=\result pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\figurewidth}{.5\textwidth}
\psset{axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=100,plotstyle=curve}
\setwindow[.5]{0}{-.5}{3}{3}{\figurewidth}
\noindent\begin{pspicture}(\xmin,\ymin)(\xmax,\ymax)
\psgrid
\psaxes[axesstyle=polar,linecolor=gray](3,90)
\psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=blue]{0}{Pi2}{sin(3*x)+2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

PS: the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) directives are included for your convenience :)

Comment: But you are using `pspicture` rather than `psgraph`.

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch that was precisely the point :)

Comment: Oh my ghost. What you did is almost identical to what I already did. I will show it shortly.